# Prove: $A$ infinite and $B$ countable, then there is an injection from $A+B$ to $A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have to prove that if $A$ is infinite and $B$ countable, then there is an injection from $A+B$ to $A$. Here, $A+B = \{(0,a)\mid a \in A \} \cup \{ (1,b) \mid b \in B \}$. I have to use that if $X$ is infinite, there is an injective function from $ \Bbb N$ to $X$.
Countable is defined as: there is a surjection from $\Bbb N$ to $B$.

Comment: Not at all, because I don't understand the interlacing and it doesn't use the statement 'if X is infinite, there is an injective function from N to X', which I have to use

Comment: I suggest you edit your answer to indicate what exactly you don’t understand about the other answer. Also please use MathJax, you can see how @RobertShore formatted your answer by clicking the “edit” button.

Comment: It's just another question. I have to use 'if X is infinite, there is an injective function from N to X'

Comment: Here is a MathJax tutorial:  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thanks. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: "If $X$ is infinite, then there is an injective function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $X$" = "We can select an enumeration of a countable subset $S$ of $X$"; namely, let $S$ be the image of $\mathbb{N}$ under the injective function.

Comment: That's true. But then?

Comment: Then you follow the answer in that duplicate. Please rephrase your question to identify what precisely you don't understand about the answer.

Comment: I don't understand the interlacing they are talking about.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4071441/let-a-b-be-some-sets-such-that-a-setminus-b-is-infinite-while-b-countable?rq=1 is also a duplicate, by the way, although the set you've denoted as $A$ is what they've denoted as $A \setminus B$ (so their $A$ is your $A + B$).

Answer (score 0):

Your question appears to be: how does the "interlacing" work in [an existing answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2997301/259262)?

To enumerate the disjoint union $A + B$ given an enumeration of $A$ and an enumeration of $B$, simply hop between the enumerations: $a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2, \dots$. In that answer, they've ensured that it's a *disjoint* union by additionally tagging each element with the set it came from: $a_i$ is tagged with a $0$, and $b_i$ is tagged with a $1$, so they've constructed the sequence $(0, a_1), (1, b_1), (0, a_2), (1, b_2), \dots$. This ensures that the sequence contains no duplicate elements that might arise if $A$ and $B$ intersected nontrivially. (This is a standard trick. Another way to solve the problem would simply be to say "use the sequence $a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2, \dots$, but omit any duplicates".)